# single word which i can use to describe all objects we use in a day such as car, cups , backpack

Tags: word-choice

I need to explain that a boy cannot identify daily routine stuff such as cups, cars, or plates. I need a single word which I can put which signifies these items.

Comment: What boy? How do you mean ‘identify’? And what type of things are you talking about? Cups, cars, and pencils are all _things_, but that's about the only thing they have in common. Your question doesn't make very much sense, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Janus: There's an infinitude of *things*, but OP is specifically asking for a word to identify all and only those which his boy is likely to encounter on a regular basis (and which therefore if he was "normal", he would know the names of).

Comment: Agnosia is probably what you are trying to describe.  Though this references a loss of neurologic function rat her than the items he cannot recognize.  You might say he is unable to recognize common or routine items.  Perhaps "items of daily living," which is reminiscent of "activities of daily living."

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about this question. It just needed some editing. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @phenry The purpose of closing an unclear question is to place it on hold until it can be clarified by editing and then reopened. That's the system working.

Comment: And that being said, the question is currently vague and will invite a long list of equally valid answers. The original poster should provide more context, such as *why* he needs this word, so answerers have a better idea what to suggest.

Answer (score 3):

They're [***everyday***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/everyday) objects/things (encountered or used routinely or typically).

I do not think there is a single everyday word for them. You'll just have to follow *everyday* with something like *items, articles* etc.

---

Entering into the spirit of things on the "long/unusual words" front, I suppose it's reasonable to assume that if OP's subject suffers from extreme [associative agnosia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agnosia), he might perhaps lead quite a restricted life, largely managed by "carers". In which case the carers might refer collectively to all the "things" he interacts with every day as his...

> [*paraphernalia*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/paraphernalia) *- miscellaneous articles, especially the equipment needed for a particular activity*

(The "particular activity" in this case being essentially "living as normal a life as possible".)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps appurtenances?  (Or maybe sundries?)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **[quotidian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/quotidian?q=quotidian)**

> ordinary or everyday, especially when mundane

Comment: Wow! *Appurtenances, mundanities, quotidian?* Those certainly aren't exactly *everyday* words! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Je ne sais quois?

Comment: Which as I understand it, goes to the very heart of OP's question. Even an articulate speaker might struggle to name the specific *Je ne sais quois* common to all those *quotidian* objects he refers to every day. But we can't just call it *commonality*, and the objects themselves *commonalities*. (Those words are already "spoken for"! :)

Answer (score 0):

So this boy has trouble recognizing the [mundanities](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mundanity) of ordinary life?
Or a little more specifically, the [mundane](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mundane) objects he encounters every day?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like 'stuff' works as well as any of the others mentioned. With the added benefit of having only one syllable. If we're dealing with a challenged individual, then it's best to use easily-digested words.

You wouldn't tell your dog to 'ensconce' when you would have him 'sit', for example.